# How to nest the same schema in mongoose js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to nest schemas using mongoose js, specifically the *same* schema, to create a tree-like structure. In this configuration, a document can only have 1 parent, but the same document can be parent to more than one child. Here's how I approached it initially:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var mySchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    parent: {
        _id: { 
            type: ObjectId, 
            ref: 'myModel'
        },
        required: true
    }
});

var myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema);

module.exports = {
    myModel: mongoose.model('myModel', myModel)
};
```

However, when I run this, I get the

`A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Undefined type "undefined" at "file.required"
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.`

I must be approaching this wrong. How do you nest the same schema using mongoose js?

Comment: Plese note that you're creating the model twice in your code example when calling `mongoose.model()` inside the `module.exports` definition as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning already show you "You can only nest using refs or arrays.". This is a mongoose design.

But what you can do is:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    objectId: String,
    parent: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MySchema'
    },
})
```

This will use a schema inside a schema, then you can use a "pre save" to update the data of your parent. Or you can use a array of refs and keep with only 1 element.

What a do is export the schemas and not the models, so you can nest it.
like this:

```
module.exports = MySchema;
```

Then I have some appModel to set the models of my collection of schemas, like this (app_model.js):

```
if(mongoose.modelNames().indexOf('mySchema') < 0) mongoose.model('mySchema', mySchema);
```

Comment: Thanks, key thing here was to use schemas, not models