# Can a mongoose schema store reference of same Schema? Help needed in storing followers of a user in social media app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a social media app, I made a user model. In its schema, I want to store the followers of the user(the same goes with following), for that, I will need to store the objectIds of those users who are following me. But can I store the objectId of the same model? I suppose not. How can I achieve this? Do I need to make a separate model for it?

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// const User = require('./user');
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        min: 5,
        max: 20
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique:true,
        min: 6
    },
    profilePicture: {
        type: String,
    },
    followers: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    following: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change the type of `following` and `follower` to **Array**  of user's `ObjectId`
and about your question below link may be useful
[How to nest the same schema in mongoose js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703088/how-to-nest-the-same-schema-in-mongoose-js)

Comment: Thank you. I made the following and follower arrays of objectId, but the type is still Ref of the same schema. The other link is useful for that. But just want to ask is that a good practice to use nested schemas for such use cases?

Comment: if I want to design models for social media, I decide to create another model like `followers` with field of `{user:ObjectId,follower:ObjectId, followername:name , followerPic:"url"}` and another for following  and add two fields in user model as the number of followers and following , because, in social media, when you want to get a list of following or follower you should use $lookup but in my design, you could find easier with low process cost